# Recurring payment(EMI) with EBS payment gateway in magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I m right now working on a E-commerce online store built on Magento and im using EBS as the payment gateway.

Will EBS payment gateway support EMI payments for the purchases made through magento recurring payments options.

And can anyone have any idea about how to create a test account for EBS payment, so that i can 
first test my application in the production environment before moving it to live.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a service that automatically calculates EMI payments or just one where you can have a recurring bill you've calculated? I don't know about EBS, but [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com) (Disclosure: I work there) has a Magento plugin and supports recurring billing, as well as having great support.

Comment: I'm looking for recurring profile support from EBS. Thanks for your response.

Comment: better you have to raise a ticket to payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge EBS does not support auto capture recurring profile.

To create a test account simply ask their support team to activate a test account.